# How to echo JSON data in datatable?

Tags: php, json, pdo, datatable

I have a Json data in a php named **json.php**, now I need to echo each data for my datatable where is in **index.php**.

My question is:

1. What is the best practice to pass json data from another php file?
2. After that, how to echo each data?

this is **json.php**, php file that generates my query into encoded JSON:

```
<?php
include "connect2.php";
$select = $con->prepare("SELECT id, dateApply, school, city, name, xType, xLevel, phone, status, lastUpdated FROM t_applicants WHERE dateApply between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'");
$select->execute();

$data = array();

    while($row=$select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $data['data'][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**index.php** > **This is body datatable code:**

```
<tbody>
   <?php
      //How to pass json.php to this code?
      //how to fetch the data from json.php?
      {?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $data['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php
         echo $apply = (new DateTime($data['dateApply']))->format('Y-m-d');
         ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['school']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['city']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['status']; ?></td>
      <td>
         <?php
            $timestamp = strtotime($data['lastUpdated']);
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
            echo $date;
            ?>
      </td>
      <td>
         <button type="button" data-a="<?php echo $data['id'];?>" data-b="<?php echo $yearX; ?>" href='#detailUpdate' class="modalDetailUpdate btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop='static' data-keyboard='false' title='Editar usuario'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
      <?php
         }?>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thank you for any help. I really Appreciate it....

Comment: Why using two different files? You can directly fetch data in one file and loop through the data to generate datatable.No need of json.php here.

Comment: I think you are asking how to code some AJAX and if that is the case as you have not attempted to do any of it yourself, the question is too broad for SO

Comment: @I.AM.SR27 good idea. applied! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($json['data'] as $row) { ?>
  <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
   ......
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and future readers.  Probably not a big deal though because this page is likely to be deleted.